# Angular 14 ng lint is giving young object promotion failed Allocation failed

Tags: angular, angular14, angular-migration

Recently I have migrated to angular 14 with node version 14.20.0, I do not have any vulnerabilities.
npm start and production build all are working fine but ng lint gives below error :

[image]

Kindly help me to solve this issue ?